# Where I can find a software that can give me my OpenGL version

Tags: opengl, version

Where I can find a software or a command in DOS that can give me my OpenGL version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [OpenGL Extensions Viewer](http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/download.html).

Answer (score 1):

I also found [OpenGL Version checker](http://www.topicscape.com/download3.php)

Answer (score 0):

another option: [wglinfo](http://www.sgi.com/products/software/opengl/examples/win32_tutorial/source/wglinfo.c), a compiled version sits around [here](http://www.cg.tuwien.ac.at/~wimmer/wglinfo/).